# How To Deployit configuration in jenkins pipeline as code in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

i found one link in google 
https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/concept/jenkins-xl-deploy-plugin.html

here the following steps are present but it is throwing

No dsl method xldCreatePackage

```
node {  
 stage('Checkout') {  
    git url: '<git_project_url>'
 }
  stage('Package') {  
    xldCreatePackage artifactsPath: 'build/libs', manifestPath: 'deployit-manifest.xml', darPath: '$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER.0.dar'  
  }  
  stage('Publish') {  
    xldPublishPackage serverCredentials: '<user_name>', darPath: '$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER.0.dar'
  }  
  stage('Deploy') {  
    xldDeploy serverCredentials: '<user_name>', environmentId: 'Environments/Dev', packageId: 'Applications/<project_name>/$BUILD_NUMBER.0'
  }  
}
```

Comment: did you install that plugin in your jenkins instance?

Comment: I installed pipeline plugin in Jenkins Instance still it is giving no dsl method found.. 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [XL Deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/XL+Deploy+Plugin) into your Jenkins installation.

Right now you have the Pipeline plugin installed which gives you the Jenkinsfile & pipeline capability only. The XebiaLabs Jenkins plugin will take advantage of that but you need to plugin to give you the functionality you want.